# Flush DNS using Java

Tags: java, dns

The usual command for flushing the system dns using command prompt is **ipconfig/flushdns**.
Is there anyway to do the same flush operation from java? Any java function to perform the same flush dns operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to run the same command using Java as:

```
     Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig /flushdns");
```

Comment: Its the same? I mean does it do the same operation?

Comment: @VarunNatraaj: Using the above syntax, you should be able to execute Windows command line operations through Java. "ipconfig/flushdns" shouldn't be any exception.