# Why is Java getting the cached version of the host name?

Tags: java

Please refer to this question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/758432/is-there-another-place-to-host-machine-name?noredirect=1#comment1132454_758432

As you can see, I'm using this method to get the machine name:

```
private InetAddress getFirstNonLoopbackAddress(boolean preferIpv4, boolean preferIPv6) throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface i = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> en2 = i.getInetAddresses(); en2.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress addr = en2.nextElement();
            if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                if (addr instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    if (preferIPv6) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    return addr;
                }
                if (addr instanceof Inet6Address) {
                    if (preferIpv4) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    return addr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The caller:

```
InetAddress ip = getFirstNonLoopbackAddress(true, false);
this.machineName = ip.getCanonicalHostName();
```

But the result is I'm getting the old machine name, before I change it in Ubuntu.

How can I get the real machine/host name as in /etc/hostname file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dns always do cache of names. You should do a flush dns in the OS that you are using; On Ubuntu I found this about how to flush the dns:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/414826/how-to-flush-dns-in-ubuntu-12-04

Or try this approach:
[Flush DNS using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150245/flush-dns-using-java)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid java from get the machine name using this way? Must I open the `/etc/hostname/` to do this ? By pointing my DNS to other server I'm getting just the machine IP now ... strange !

Comment: If you change you DNS server the dns cache will be updated in you OS, that's normal and you will get correct IP address.

Comment: A possible solution as pointed in original question (AskUbuntu) is to add a external IP entry in `/etc/hosts` with the name I want to display. Java will no longer ask it to the DNS server.